# Trouble with loading external html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external

So I thought it'd be really nice to have all my page elements like navbar, carousel, footer etc externalized and then load them through jQuery into parent page. I'm using Brackets which has live preview that showed all elements and all worked properly there. The problems began when I tested it in real browsers.
I tested in Chrome, Opera and Firefox and only Firefox would show the content loaded through jQuery.

Here's what parent page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="navLoader"></div>
    <div id="carouselLoader"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is jQuery that loads elements:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#navLoader").load("components/navbar.html");
    $("#carouselLoader").load("components/carousel.html");
});
```

Loading troubles aside, is this a good practice to keep page elements separate? It feels much tidier and easier to work with, but that doesn't mean that it is necessarily good from a technical standpoint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a js templating language such as Handlebars or mustacheJS??

Comment: Sorry I'm completely new to web development so I'm still working with basics :)

Comment: please search about 'import' tag, which may be supported in future browser. It has same concept. I like such architecture that browser can build a site dynamically from html modules loaded from server.